# HTML tags or CSS properties

Tags: html, css

So I was wondering what's better to use - HTML tags or CSS properties?

We have both HTML tags and CSS properties for same purpose in various cases, like in `<img>` tag one can use `width` and `height` html values to assign them or can use `css` properties for same purpose.

Then, to center some text, or some other contents too, one can use `<center>Some text here</center>` or css property `text-align:center;`

To make some text italic, one can use `<i>` or `<em>` html tag or use equivalent css properties. (Though `<i>` has a different meaning in HTML5, but still it's used.)

There are many similar cases. So, what's more acceptable and better to use?

Comment: It's more acceptable to use CSS.

Comment: @War10ck Why so? Some specific reason or just as an assumption?

Comment: It's more acceptable to use CSS - if is for presentation purposes and not otherwise.

Comment: fyi, <center> is deprecated.

Comment: @ZachL - It's substitute? CSS? Or some other HTML tag?

Comment: CSS. `<center>` has no semantic value and does have explicit presentational value. HTML is not for presentation and most presentational features of it have been stripped out.

Comment: `<center>` has died in the same hole where `<font>`, `<marquee>` and `<color>` have been rotting for not long enough now.

Comment: The question calls for extended argumentation and opinions and tends to spawn them, rather than solid technical arguments. Words like “better” and “acceptable” lead to discussions without consensus, especially when no criteria for goodness have been set.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - That's what I exactly wanted. But as everyone was just answering that way, I accepted one of those answers only. Would you please mind giving some nice argumentation? I'd like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this age of HTML5, I would opt to not use any HTML attributes that [were already marked deprecated for its predecessors HTML 4.01 and XHTML](http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/a/bltags_deprctag.htm), such as `width`, `border`, `height` etc.

For layout, use CSS, for semantics, use HTML. The `border` attribute serves no other purpose nowadays than enable legacy IE5.5 sites to still work.

As for the questions about `<i>` and `<b>` I'd recommend reading up a bit on **why** you should only write semantic HTML, [for example here](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/).

More general reading about why HTML is not for layout/presentation can [even be found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content).

Comment: I may be confused, but I think width/height attributes are fine (even reccommended) in HTML5.

Comment: @ZachL Only on `img` tags since they make semantic sense there.

Comment: What's semantic HTML exactly?

Comment: @k_programmer how about you click those 2 links in my answer instead of asking me to copy/paste them.

Comment: @Niels Okay. Sorry :P

Comment: @k_programmer, Logical meaning of what a html tag represents is basically a one line of `semantic HTML`.

Answer (score 4):

If it's presentation - use CSS. If its structure/semantics - use HTML.

To take the italic example, there are lots of reasons for wanting text to be rendered in italics. Let the reason define the markup you use (which could be `<em>`, `<cite>`, `<dfn>` or many other elements), then add CSS as desired to get the presentation you want (taking common browser default styles for the elements you use into account).

Comment: *If it's presentation - use CSS. If its structure/semantics - use HTML.* May you please elaborate?

Comment: I did. That's what the whole second paragraph is doing.

Comment: I tend to use `<i>` if, for example, I'm reproducing a written paper digitally. It explicitly says its italic, which is semantically correct if I'm describing a written document.

Comment: If I was reproducing a written paper, then I'd look for the semantics that the typography implied and use those in my HTML.

Comment: The fun thing about using multiple italic markup is nesting :).  Browser default styles get it wrong - e.g. `<i class="ship name">` nested inside `<em>` should reset back to non-italic.  You end up with a combinatorial explosion of CSS selectors - em i, em cite, etc.  It's quite annoying if you have a novel with pervasive use of italics to represent characters' thoughts, for example.

Answer (score 1):

To give some concrete answers without the more general principles:

HTML5 says not to use `<centre>`.  It is marked as obsolete and non-conforming.  Here's a link to the [full list of such features](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features).

Use `<i>` for most inline italics.  If you don't mind using both, use `<em>` where the italics indicate emphasis :).  If that seems like too much effort, just use `<i>`.  Most people do, and (because of this) in practice you're unlikely to see much difference in behaviour.  It's good to use markup for inline italics, so it can degrade gracefully if CSS support breaks - this could be more common than you think, e.g. when copying+pasting from some browser.

The most obvious exception would be if your design used an italic font for headings.  For that case you should use CSS.

`<img width>` is probably subject to argument... but in general much of the layout in your design should be in CSS.  So you want to put the width of images in CSS rather than HTML, to keep these layout details together.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of CSS is that you can aply classes to various elements you wish have the same behaviour.

If for instance you suddenly want your images to be 10px bigger in width and height, in CSS you change those values in only one place, whereas in HTML you have to go through all your code changing the values! :)

Answer (score 0):

This topic is quite debatable in my opinion. HTML tags and its attributes have a **semantic** meaning behind it where as CSS is entirely focused on the layout and styles. HTML5 adds a new brand semantic tags.

Tags like `<strong>` have much more meaning then `font-weight:bold`. The css property only makes the text appear bold, but the HTML tag `<strong>` strengthens the content (You can see the difference through a text reader).

However, new generation of web focuses more on the style than on the HTML structure, so there is not a fixed rule on how it should be followed. So I suggest concentrating one factor and that is **manageability**. Select the option which you can manage and maintain easily.

Comment: Ah, the "new generation of web focuses more on the style than on" doing it right and being accessible. Other developers taking crappy shortcuts shouldn't be a reason to do the same thing.

Comment: @Quentin, We cannot blame them entirely too. The web market is overly misguided over the topic of valid HTML structure and good looking template.